# print of jeditor pane

Tags: java, swing, printing, awt, jeditorpane

In swing i have a component JEditorPane with JScrollPane i want to take print out of the content of jeditorpane. and i should have the flexibility to change the heading of printing page at runtime. I am using the following code but its not working

```
 try{
  JEditorPane editorpane1= new JEditorPane();
  editorpane1.setContentType("text/html");
  editorpane1.setEditable(false);
  File file1= new File("path of the html file");
  URL url= new URL(file1);
  editorpane1.setPage(url);
  JScrollPane jsp= new JScrollPane(editorpane1);
  editorpane1.print();
  }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {

  }
```

Comment: printing to the File or Printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the editor kit independet printer http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html

To add page headers just modify root view's paint() method adding your content above.